# Having trouble with the syntax in line 33

Tags: python, slack-api, twilio-api

I am building a slackbot, and am trying to receive sms messages from slack. Here is my python code

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from slackclient import SlackClient
from twilio import twiml
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

SLACK_WEBHOOK_SECRET = os.environ.get('SLACK_WEBHOOK_SECRET', None)
WILIO_NUMBER = os.environ.get('TWILIO_NUMBER', None)
USER_NUMBER = os.environ.get('USER_NUMBER', None)

app = Flask(__name__)
slack_client = SlackClient(os.environ.get('SLACK_TOKEN', None))
twilio_client = TwilioRestClient()


@app.route('/twilio', methods=['POST'])
def twilio_post():
    response = twiml.Response()
    if request.form['From'] == USER_NUMBER:
        message = request.form['Body']
        slack_client.api_call("chat.postMessage", channel="#general",
              text=message, username='twiliobot',
              icon_emoji=':robot_face:')
    return Response(response.toxml(), mimetype="text/xml"), 200


@app.route('/slack', methods=['POST'])
def slack_post():
    if request.form['token'] == SLACK_WEBHOOK_SECRET:
        channel = request.form['channel_name']
        username = request.form['user_name']
        text = request.form['text']
        response_message = username   " in "   channel   " says: "   text
        twilio_client.messages.create(to=USER_NUMBER,    from_=TWILIO_NUMBER,
                                  body=response_message)
return Response(), 200


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def test():
   return Response('It works!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image]

When I try running this code with "python twiliobot.py", because it is the name of the app, it returns this error:

> File "twiliobot.py", line 33 response_message = username   " in "
>   channel   " says: "   text

[image]
What am I doing wrong here? What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Are you trying to join strings?  Add `+` signs between them.

Comment: You missed the actual error message.

Comment: Also some of your code is indented wrong. (the return statement for `slack_post`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the line in question

```
response_message = username   " in "   channel   " says: "   text
```

I assume you're trying to concatenate text.  Use the `+` operator

```
response_message = username  + " in "  + channel  + " says: "  + text
```

Or `join`

```
response_message = ' '.join([username, "in", channel, "says:",text]
```

or `format`

```
response_message = '{} in {} says: {}'.format(username, channel, text)
```

Comment: Actually, that works perfectly. The code was given, so I was not entirely sure what was going on. Super simple, can't believe I missed it.